# CRS undefined when copying to new layer, QGIS 2.18.12

Tags: qgis-2.18, vector-layer, copy

I'm using QGIS 2.18.12 and have this problem:

When I copy objects and paste them into a new layer, I get the message CRS undefined. (I'm using EPSG:28992, Amersfoort/RD New as CRS). In the long term release 2.14 version, I get the same message, but I get a window to change the CRS. In the 2.18.12 version, there is no window to change the CRS, actually, and this is pretty annoying, QGIS stops the whole action. In short, I can't paste objects anymore into new layers.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Go to QGIS / Preferences / CRS:

[image]

You have to select **Prompt for CRS**, maybe you have set **Use a default CRS: EPSG:28992, Amersfoort/RD**.

Comment: Thank you but this solves the problem with the CRS, but then still nothing happens. In 2.14.16 I get a window for CRS and then I get the window for saving the New vector layer. In 2.18.12 I have the same window for CRS but then nothing, there is no window for saving the new vector layer.